# Classes in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, macos, class

I have a class named person, with two values: age and weight.Why can't I access these two values in the main function like this:

`int a=[chuck age];
int b=[chuck weight];`

What is the best way to do that? Using properties is the correct way?

Header file:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
    @interface person : NSObject
    {
        int age;
        int weight;
    }
    -(void) print;
    -(void) setAge;
    -(void) setWeight;

@end
```

Implementation file:

```
#import "person.h"

@implementation person

-(void) print
{
    printf("Your age is %d and your weight is %d.", age, weight);
}

-(void) setAge
{
    printf("Write age: ");
    int v;
    scanf("%d", &v);
    age=v;
}

-(void) setWeight
{
    printf("Write weight: ");
    int g;
    scanf("%d", &g);
    weight=g;
}

@end
```

Comment: You need to declare properties for these members (or more correctly getter methods). Post your class header file

Comment: You need to show more info, how are you initialising ? and what's the class interface  (properties/methods,etc..)?

Comment: of course better way is property but you can get value by KVC like this: int a = [chuck valueForKey: @"age"];

Comment: Great, and how are you setting `age` and `weight` in the class implementation ?, you might be setting wrong values in the `setAge` and `setWeight` methods.


Yes you can use properties, but this should work too and we need to find out your mistake instead of avoiding it by using Properties :)

Comment: How come your `setAge` and `setWeight` methods don't take a parameter? Don't you need to pass in a value that you want to set? You need to find a good tutorial on Objective-C and learn about properties.

Comment: maddy, i'm setting the age with scanf.

Comment: And how do you init the `Chuck` instance ? , can you put `NSLog(@"Scanned Age:%d, setAge:%d", v, age);` after you scan age in `setAge` method and show what's the output ? trying to make sure you're getting correct values first

Comment: Perfect, got your problem, posting a detailed answer now, give me a second :)

Comment: Main.m file:

    `#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
    #import "person.h"
    
    int main(int argc, char *argV[])
    {
        @autoreleasepool {
            
            person *andrew = [[person alloc]init];
            [andrew setAge];
            [andrew setWeight];
            [andrew print];
        }
        return 0;
    }`

Comment: BTW:  `person` should be `Person`;  Objective-C classes always start with a capital letter.  Note that if your goal is to write OS X or iOS applications, this is quite the odd place to start.  Not bad -- nothing wrong with learning Unix command line goop -- just nothing like what you'll need to know to write apps.

Comment: i'm learning objective-c. I think command line is a great place to start(my newbie opinion) :)

Comment: @AndreiDiaconu Start there if you want as there is certainly value in doing so (I started there mostly because I had to when I started ObjC programming :).  However and again, if your goal is to learn OS X or iOS programming, you should structure your code properly.   What Mostafa suggests below will work for your code, but it is flat out wrong in the context of an OS X or iOS application, including command line utilities targeting OS X.

Comment: so you say it is better to use properties?

Comment: @AndreiDiaconu See my answer below.  You could use instance variables and manually implement the getter/setter pair in the normal way, if you want, but it is a waste of code.   Properties take care of automatically synthesizing the instance variable and all setter/getter code for you (and have several additional advantages).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Are you working from some kind of a tutorial or book?  That is an odd place to start for learning to write OS X or iOS apps.

In any case, the issue is that you've colluded getter/setter stuff with methods that implement other functionality.

I would suggest that your `Person` class be declared as:

```
 @interface Person : NSObject
 @property NSInteger age;
 @property NSInteger weight;
 @end
```

With Person.m:

```
 @implementation Person
 - (id) init {
     self = [super init];
     if (self) {
          // preposterous initial values so we know if they weren't set.
          _age = -1;
          _weight = -1; 
     }
     return self;
 }
 @end
```

That is, a `Person` only holds information about a single person.  It does not do any kind of I/O, etc...

Then, your main.m would look something like:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "Person.h"

NSInteger ScanIntegerWithPrompt(NSString *prompt) {
    printf("%s: ", [prompt UTF8String]);
    int v;
    scanf("%d", &v);
    return (NSInteger) v;
}

int main(...) {
    @autoreleasepool {
      Person *p = [[Person alloc] init];
      p.age = ScanIntegerWithPrompt(@"Enter age:");
      p.weight = ScanIntegerWithPrompt(@"Enter weight:");
      printf("Your age is %d and your weight is %d", p.age, p.weight);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Structuring the code this way separates the Model -- the data container -- from the Control layer.  There isn't much of a  View layer here.

If you *really* wanted to keep the I/O / parse logic with the `Person` object, then add something like this to the Person object:

```
...
- (NSNumber)readIntegerWithPrompt:(NSString*)prompt
{
    ... same code as function above ...
}

- (void)readAgeFromStandardInput
{
   self.age = [self readIntegerWithPrompt:@"Enter age: "];
}

- (void)readWeightFromStandardInput
{
   self.weight = [self readIntegerWithPrompt:@"Enter weight: "];
}
...
```

Then you'd call those methods from your `main`.

Comment: Great answer, but didn't you meant to define the property types as `NSInteger` rather than `NSNumber`? Also, if the ivars were autosynthesized, they'd be prefixed with underscores (when referenced in the `init` method).

Comment: Yes and yes... SO needs a compiler to catch my stupid mistakes.

Comment: Not stupid, just human. One of the great things about SO though is the readers tend to fill in for the compiler, albeit with a lot more latency getting errors and warnings. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is You're trying to access private `age` and `weight` ivars, which aren't accessible this way.

The good way to do this is to use ObjC properties, but this is not required for your example.

You need to create two methods to access the private ivars, call them `age` and `weight`, they should look like this in the class interface:

```
- (int) age;
- (int) weight;
```

and the implementation is:

```
- (int) age{
   return age;
}

- (int) weight{
   return weight;
}
```

Now in your main.m you can easily access the data needed like this:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "person.h"
int main(int argc, char *argV[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        person *andrew = [[person alloc]init];
        [andrew setAge];
        [andrew setWeight];
        NSLog(@"Age:%d, Weight:%d",[andrew age], [andrew weight]);
    }
return 0;
}
```

If you want to know how it's done with properties please let me know and I can update the answer :)

Comment: You're very welcome, things can be done in a much better way though, I think you seem to be new to Objective-C or OOP world, if that's the case you can read the apple docs and some objective-C tutorials.

there are very good beginner ObjC tutorials on tutsplus.com :)

Comment: Getters in Objective-C are **never** prefixed with `get`.

Comment: An improvement! You're still implying that `setAge` and `setWeight` are OK.  They aren't.   Sure, they don't conflict with `setAge:` and `setWeight:`, but that'd be an awful API to program against!

Comment: @bbum, I totally agree with you and I didn't imply that they're right, But seeing OP's question, I was only showing why his code wasn't working, not the right way to do it, I'll probably improve the answer and show how it's properly done later tonight :), thanks

Answer (score 0):

In your header file :

```
@property int age;
@property int weight;
```